# Rails - Trying to set cookies from Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, cookies

I am trying to set cookies for users that aren't signed in on the create action of a form.  Once a non-signed in user hits submit, they are redirected to a sign-in/signup action, where they then return back to the page they were previously on and the form auto populates with their previously entered info.

I have successfully added the cookies and they are saving, but they are returning a weird string object.

```
"{\"1\"=>\"This is a test answer\"}" # 1 is the question_id and 'This is a test answer' is the answer_text
```

Here is the create action where I am setting the cookies:

```
def create 
  store_location  

 if current_user.nil?
   cookies[:answer_entry] = { :value => params[:answers] }
   # raise p cookies[:answer_entry].inspect 
   deny_access
 else 
   params[:answers].each do |question_id, answer_text|
     next if answer_text.blank?
     question = Question.find(question_id)
     question.answers.create!(:answer => answer_text, :user_id => current_user )
     raise p question.answer
     redirect_to book_questions_path(@book), :notice => "You have successfully submitted your Answer, please answer more!"
   end
  end 
end
```

I then save the cookies to an instance variable in the show action (which is where the form appears) and then pass in the variable as a value in the form:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id]) 
  @question = @book.questions.find(params[:id])

  if user_signed_in?
    @answer = cookies[:answer_entry]
  else
   cookies[:answer_entry] = nil 
  end
end
```

And

```
<%= form_for(:answer, :url => book_question_answers_path(@book, @question)) do |f| %>
  <%= text_area_tag "answers[#{@question.id}]", @answer%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user %> 
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

And from this I am getting that weird string auto populating in the form field.

I have two questions:

1. I understand that this is a string  "{\"1\"=>\"This is a test answer\"}"  But can someone explain why there is a hash within and why the double quotes are being escaped?
2. I want to render ONLY the answer_text ("this is a test answer") in the form field, can someone point me in the right direction to solve this? Do I have to split up the string and reassign it as a hash and then call the :answer_text params?

I appreciate any and all help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a hash in cookies[:answer_entry] that is why when you retrieve it and store it in the @answer instance variable you get back a hash and when you use it in the text_area_tag it shows up as a string.

There are a couple of ways to address this

Way one

In the create action assign to the cookies[:answer_entry] as follows

```
cookies[:answer_entry] = params[:answers]
```

Way Two

In show action retrieve the value from cookies[:answer_entry] as follows

```
@answer = cookies[:answer_entry][:value]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I do way one I get: `undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for {"1"=>"asdadad"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` and with way two I get: `can't convert Symbol into Integer` . Do I have to change something in the view as well?